# Show that $f'(x)>\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, proof-writing, convex-analysis

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. Suppose that $f(0)=0$ and that $f'$ is strictly increasing. Show that $f'(x)>\frac{f(x)}{x}$. I would like to know if my proof holds, please and to have a feedback.

First, as $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $f'$ is strictly increasing, then it is convex on $(0,1)$. Thus, we have the following inequality for $h<x<x+h$ ($h>0$ and such that $x+h<1$):

$\frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}\le\frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{x}\le \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Applying the limit as $h\to 0$ we obtain

$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}\le \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$ as wanted.

Comment: You did not get strict inequality.

Comment: There is an error, the fact the question states that $f'$ is increasing, not $f$. Hence on the interval, we know for certain only that if $x_1 >x_2 \implies f'(x_1) > f'(x_2)$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Yes, I misstyped $f$ instead of $f'$ in the proof, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You proof is fine if you say that $f'$ is increasing (not $f$). However, you only get that $f'(x)\ge\frac{f(x)}{x}$, not the strict inequality.

Here is another (possibly simpler) approach which also gives the strict inequality: From the mean-value theorem we have for $x > 0$
$$
 f(x) = f(x) - f(0) = f'(c) (x-0)
$$
for some $c \in (0, x)$. Since $f'$ is strictly increasing it follows that
$$
 f(x) = f'(c) x < f'(x) x
$$
which is the desired estimate.

Comment: Ah, yes. I wanted to write $f'$ is increasing not $f$ (misstyped). Thank you for an another approach!

Comment: @Daniil: Yes, the mean-value theorem states that for $a < b$,  $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c) (b-a)$ with some $c$ **strictly between** $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Have a nice day!